# How can i restrict the user in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have created user with read permissions in Mongodb. I have done the same process [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

but still user was not restricted with permissions.User can create the collection and insert the document but user have only read permissions.
When I opened `mongo.exe`, it was showing some warnings.

```
ongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
Server has startup warnings:
2018-09-17T01:11:07.042-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
**2018-09-17T01:11:07.042-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-09-17T01:11:07.042-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.******
2018-09-17T01:11:07.042-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
---
```

So how can i restrict the user in MongoDB?

Answer (score 3):

So, you are missing few things in configure section.
you need to activate in the mongod configuration file.
it will be located in `/etc/mongod.conf` if you are using Linux.
you need to change/uncomment/add this section below:

```
security:
    authorization: "enabled"
```

and after that you need to restart mongod service.
in my case service name is `mongod` .
so i did `sudo systemctl restart mongod` .
and as you already having role. and authentication enabled just now.
you have to login now.

```
>> mongo --port <YOUR_MONGO_PORT>
> use admin
>  db.auth("username","password")
```

it should login now.

all steps:

1. Create Users with needed Roles.
2. Enable Authetication in DB config level.
3. Dont forget to Restart The Database service.
4. Try To login. You are Good to Go.

You can look into this medium post as well [here](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac).

Comment: I am using windows OS. and more over i tried enabled authorization and restart mongodb server but mongodb server was not restart,it was showing error like windows could not start the MongoDB server service on local computer.  Error 1053: the service didn't respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.  I have changed the service location local to network but still it was not restarted.

Comment: @Ramesh what is the command you using to start the mongoDb server? if using any command can you try restarting it with `--auth` ?

Comment: thank for your update. I got the solution. As you mentioned in the above process is workable but one small change. Before enable security authorization, first we need create one user in the database then we will enable the security authorization. it is working.

Comment: Great to know that @Ramesh and thanks for the correction.